# Trying to insert data into a Microsoft Access database

Tags: c#, database, oledbconnection

I'm trying to insert data into a Microsoft Access database using windows forms but no data is being inserted to the table in the database.

Here's the button method.

```
private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     try
     {
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Clinic Inventory System.accdb;
            Persist Security Info=False;";
            conn.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Patient(FirstName,LastName,ContactNumber) VALUES(@fname,@lname,@contactnumber)";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", txtBoxFirstName.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", txtBoxLastName.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contactnumber", txtBoxContactNumber.Text);
            //command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Patient (FirstName,LastName,ContactNumber) VALUES('" + txtBoxFirstName.Text + "','" + txtBoxLastName.Text + "','" + txtBoxContactNumber.Text + "')";

            command.Connection = conn;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

           MessageBox.Show("Patient Registered");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error  " + ex);
            MessageBox.Show("test");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: You are probably looking in the wrong database.  Happens a lot when you have a copy in the DataDirectory.

Comment: Where is your access DB located? Data Source=|DataDirectory|\[Clinic Inventory System].accdb if you have space in your DB name then use [] to enclose it.

Comment: Tried removing the backslash and still not inserting data. The database is located where the project classes are stored.

Comment: How many coloumns are there in your table?

Comment: Three. FirstName, LastName & ContactNumber

Comment: Try (just temporarily, for fault isolation): 1. Specify full access file path in the ConnectionString; 2. Check the ExecuteNonQuery return value - it should be 1 (rows affected). 3. Try executing your query in Access Query window and see if it works. 4. Tell us what happens if you run the commented out command text, without the @ parameters - does it work?